# How to send data using ajax to a node server without jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to learn how to send data using ajax. When the submit button is clicked, I want Ajax to send the data to a particular route, unrelated to the data and a route associated with the form. However, Ajax doesn't seem to be sending anything. I added three `console.log()` statement in my script but none of them are being displayed.

**HTML and AJAX code**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <form class="" action="/submitData" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button id="submitForm" type="submit">Submit</button>

    <script>
      const el = document.getElementById(submitForm);
      if (el) {
        el.addEventListener('submit', addRecipe);
        console.log('Step 1');
      }


      function addRecipe() {

        var recipe = {
          param1: 'value1',
          param2: 'value2'
        };

        console.log('step 2')

        let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open("POST", "/add-recipe", true);
        //Specify the type of data to be sent
        xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        xml.send(JSON.stringify(recipe));
        console.log('step 3');
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**server.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(7000);

app.post('/add-recipe', function(req, res) {
  var recipe = req.body.recipe;
  console.log(recipe);
});

app.post('/submitData',urlencodedParser,function(req, res){

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when the `submit` button is clicked, the `form` will be submitted, so the page/data will be directly redirected to the `action` page.

That's why your `addRecipe()` function is not executed because the page is redirected before its execution.

So if you want to execute the `addRecipe()` function and send the `data` via Ajax before submitting the form, you need to prevent the default form submition, execute your code and then submit the `form`:

```
function addRecipe(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var recipe = {
      param1: 'value1',
      param2: 'value2'
    };

    console.log('step 2')

    let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("POST", "/add-recipe", true);
    //Specify the type of data to be sent
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xml.send(JSON.stringify(recipe));
    console.log('step 3');

    //Get the form and submit it
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `type="button"` to your submit button and use `preventDefault` to make xmlhttp request...

```js
const el = document.getElementById("submitForm");
      if (el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', addRecipe);
        console.log('Step 1');
      }


      function addRecipe(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var recipe = {
          param1: 'value1',
          param2: 'value2'
        };

        console.log('step 2')

        let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open("POST", "/add-recipe", true);
        //Specify the type of data to be sent
        xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        xml.send(JSON.stringify(recipe));
        console.log('step 3');
        }
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <form class="" action="/submitData" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button id="submitForm" type="submit" type="button">Submit</button>

  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I never knew you could have more then one type attached to one element. Thank you. However, can up update you answer an explain why attaching  type ="submit to both the form and the even listener isn't working? Also, can you please explain what `e.preventDefault();` does an why it's need?